# Different serverTokenEndpoint for login and registration

Tags: authentication, ember.js, registration, ember-simple-auth

I'm using ember-simple-auth for logging in a user which is working fine. For logging a user in, I've to ping this endpoint: `/auth/sign_in`.

However, for registering a new user, I've to ping a different endpoint: `/auth`.

If I'm trying to use the ember-simple-auth for also registering (as instructed in this blog: http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/building-user-registration-with-ember-simple-auth/), I'm facing the issue that Ember is pinging the same endpoint (as specified in the `serverTokenEndpoint`).

How can I register a new user using ember-simple-auth?

Answer (score 0):

User creation on signup goes through the Ember Data adapter, not the Ember Simple Auth authenticator so it won't use the `serverTokenEndpoint` you configure for the authenticator but the `host`/`namespace` you configured for the adapter.